# Change DHCP lease time on VirtualBox

Tags: networking, vagrant, virtualbox, dhcp

My company is using VirtualBox+Hostmanager as our Vagrant provider. We have **plenty** of different projects which each gets its own setup attached so we ended up with a meta-project of sorts which contains just the Vagrant stuff:

- `projectA/`
- `projectB/`
- `projectC/`

Inside each project we have a layout like:

```
projectA/ 
    puppet/
    src/        # project's source, not part of meta-project, auto-created
    Puppetfile
    Vagrantfile
```

`src/` gets created by Vagrant provisioning and is checked out each from its own VCS project. So, if working on `projectB`, you just go to that folder, `vagrant up` (which starts or creates the required machine, checks out source if needed, sets up www.projectB.dev hosts entry on your machine and you're good to go), you work on it and then `vagrant halt` or `vagrant destroy`. This all works mostly well.

The problem is that VirtualBox's DHCP server (which provides the dynamic IP address for each box) gives out a really short lease (like, a day or two). As not every project is being worked  daily, those machines aren't up to renew their lease and I end up with `/etc/hosts` like:

```
172.28.128.4    projectA # used
172.28.128.3    projectB
172.28.128.5    projectC
172.28.128.4    projectD # reused :(
```

This is not ideal for my situation as it becomes unmanageable after a while, especially with non-networking-savy frontend guys.

So, is there a way around this, either by changing the lease time on the VirtualBox DHCP server or even for the client (the base box is always a custom CentOS 6 build)? I could go the static IP route per project, but as it opens another can of worms, I'm looking at it like a last resort.

Comment: There are some [VirtualBox DHCP](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-dhcpserver) settings you can change, but I don't see anything in there about lease times. I'm using static private IPs for some of my multi-node projects just so the nodes are at consistent locations (e.g. see the Vagrantfile under https://github.com/bcantoni/vagrant-cassandra/tree/master/2.MultiNode).

Comment: Yes, static IPs are not really a good fit here because I expect a lot of different Vagrant projects and it would become cumbersome to mantain a list of static IPs for each user. I got a suggestion to try to replace the entire hostmanager part with [Consul](https://www.consul.io/) which could be used as a authoritative DNS server on each workstation and gets updates after each Vagrant boot with the proper IP. The short lease time becomes a non-issue, I'm working on implementing it, will report back if successful.